# Vertical line on Amcharts instead of the grid

Tags: amcharts

How can I set the vertical lines related to the Category Axis which are NOT the grid ? 
Watch the pictures to see what I m looking for.
It s not the grid, I don't think it's neither a trend line nor a guide. It s related to the data.

Any help will be deeply appreciated.

(I tryed to use the Editor to find it out... no magical result lol)

[Amchart picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4IWa.png)

[amchart my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zs6TC.png)

Comment: It certainly looks like the grid to me. I don't see any other way to make those lines. [Demo](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/97c7801ee47f5843774f1f983f0ce0a4)

Comment: Thank you very much, @xorspark. Your demo looks perfect to me.

Comment: @xorspark When I apply your demo to my amchart, i don't have the same effect. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zs6TC.png

Comment: I can't troubleshoot a screenshot. :) Post your code, please.

Comment: If you're using a date-based axis, try setting `equalSpacing` to true in your `categoryAxis`. [Demo](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/fb5e64711b5e6cb9ccb27b6cd33f317a?editors=0010). If that doesn't help, then post a fiddle, not a screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I fixed my problem :

somewhere after "type": "serial",

```
        "gridAboveGraphs": true,  // to get the vertical lines above the graph
```

And I added in              "categoryAxis": { ... }

```
            "gridAlpha": 1,  // to make the vertical lines appear
            "gridColor": "#ffffff",   // to set the color of the lines
            "gridPosition": "middle",   // instead of 'start' to see the lines like I wanted
```

I wanna thank people who tried to help me. 
Best regards.